# React Giving Me: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" but will post anyway

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core

jumping on a react project for my company but I am not super familiar with it. We have a bug where when a user posts something, we get this error but if you refresh, the post is there anyway. Any hints?

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'comment') 
 src/Components/Main/Dispatch/DispatchDetails/DispatchDetails.tsx:1552
1549 | {   dispatch.comments &&
1550 |     dispatch.comments.map((story, index) =>
1551 |     <div key={index}>
> 1552 |         {story.comment.split('\n').map((remark, indexRem) => {
1553 |             if(remark === '') {
1554 |                 return <br key={indexRem} />;
1555 |             }

src/Components/Main/Dispatch/DispatchDetails/DispatchDetails.tsx:1550
 1547 | <h3 style={boldStyle}>Dispatch Comments:</h3>
 1548 | <div className="well-story">
 1549 |     {   dispatch.comments &&
 > 1550 |         dispatch.comments.map((story, index) =>
 1551 |         <div key={index}>
 1552 |             {story.comment.split('\n').map((remark, indexRem) => {
 1553 |                 if(remark === '') {
```

**Code**

```
         <div className="well-story">
              {   dispatch.comments &&
                  dispatch.comments.map((story, index) =>
         <div key={index}>
             {story.comment.split('\n').map((remark, indexRem) => {
             if(remark === '') {
             return <br key={indexRem} />;
             }
             return <p key={indexRem} className="the-remark">{remark}</p>;
              })
            }
              <p className="remark-datetime">
            {story.commentBy + ' | ' + moment(story.commentDate, 'X').format('LLL')}
         </p>
         </div>
         ) }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Story object is empty in the second loop hence this error was there, because the first loop had story object fine, it processed fine, but the next object was empty, hence shown an error. Below code should fix your issue.

```html
 <div className="well-story">
              {   dispatch.comments &&
                  dispatch.comments.map((story, index) =>
         <div key={index}>
             {story && story.comment && story.comment.split('\n').map((remark, indexRem) => {
             if(remark === '') {
             return <br key={indexRem} />;
             }
             return <p key={indexRem} className="the-remark">{remark}</p>;
              })
            }
              <p className="remark-datetime">
            {story.commentBy + ' | ' + moment(story.commentDate, 'X').format('LLL')}
         </p>
         </div>
         ) }
        </div>
```

Comment: Almost right but `story` is not `empty`, It should be `undefined`. If Is is empty object as `{}`, then there wouldn't be any errror.

Comment: @decpk interesting, can you provide more clarity to your thinking? Not sure if I understand your second sentence.

Comment: `store` is `undefined` that's why you are getting the error. @Jigesh answer is perfect but the explanation is not correct. What I mean is *Story object is empty*, `Story` object can't be empty. Let say `const story = {}`, then you won't get error if you log out `story.comment`. because you are trying to get the value from empty not from "undefined". now try to do as `const story = undefined`, and log `story.comment`. You would get error.

Comment: @decpk Thanks! That helped a lot, the above code worked but then it just broke on story.commentBy so I assumed there was part of the logic that I am not quite grasping. I appreciate it.